# Error en `apt-get upgrade` o `apt-get install` en Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Al intentar instalar un paquete me da el siguiente resultado:

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Tal vez quiera ejecutar «apt --fix-broken install» para corregirlo.
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:

                                      Depende: libpixman-1-0 (>= 0.30.0) pero no va a instalarse
                                      Depende: libx11-xcb1 pero no va a instalarse
                                      Depende: libxcb-sync1 pero no va a instalarse
                                      Depende: libxcb-util1 (>= 0.4.0) pero no va a instalarse
                                      Depende: libxcb1 pero no va a instalarse
                                      Depende: libxcursor1 (> 1.1.2) pero no va a instalarse
                                      Depende: libxrandr2 (>= 2:1.2.99.2) pero no va a instalarse
                                      Depende: libxrender1 pero no va a instalarse
                                      Depende: libxtst6 pero no va a instalarse
                                      Depende: libxv1 pero no va a instalarse
                                      Depende: libxvmc1 pero no va a instalarse
                                      Depende: xorg-video-abi-24
                                      Depende: xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 (>= 2:1.18.99.901) pero no va a instalarse
 xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04 : Depende: xorg-video-abi-24
                                    Depende: xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 (>= 2:1.18.99.901) pero no va a instalarse
 xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04 : Depende: libdrm-radeon1 (>= 2.4.39) pero no va a instalarse
                                       Depende: xorg-video-abi-24
                                       Depende: xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 (>= 2:1.18.99.901) pero no va a instalarse
 xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04 : Depende: xorg-video-abi-24
                                     Depende: xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 (>= 2:1.18.99.901) pero no va a instalarse
 xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04 : Depende: libdrm2 (>= 2.4.60) pero no va a instalarse
                                       Depende: libxatracker2 (>= 11.1.0~) pero no va a instalarse
                                       Depende: xorg-video-abi-24
                                       Depende: xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 (>= 2:1.18.99.901) pero no va a instalarse
 zenity : Depende: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.19.12) pero no va a instalarse
          Depende: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) pero no va a instalarse
          Depende: zenity-common (>= 3.28.1-1) pero no va a instalarse
//Unos 1000 mas de esos y luego
E: Dependencias incumplidas. Intente «apt --fix-broken install» sin paquetes (o especifique una solución).
```

Al intentar `apt --fix-broken install` obtengo la siguiente respuesta al final:

```
dpkg: error: leyendo el fichero info del paquete '/var/lib/dpkg/status': Error de entrada/salida
E: El subproceso dpkg --set-selections devolvió un código de error (2)
E: Couldn't record the approved state changes as dpkg selection states
```

Intenté corregirlo con `cp /var/lib/dpkg/status{,.backup}`
y obtuve lo siguiente:

```
root@andoshy:/home/princess# sed -i.backup -e '/^Package: \(libecryptfs0\|libplexus-containers1\.5-Java\|apport\)$/,/^$/d' /var/lib/dpkg/status
sed: error al leer de /var/lib/dpkg/status: Error de entrada/salida
```

Cuando intento con `sudo apt-get -f install`
recibo la siguiente respuesta

```
dpkg: error: leyendo el fichero info del paquete '/var/lib/dpkg/status': Error de entrada/salida
E: El subproceso dpkg --set-selections devolvió un código de error (2)
E: Couldn't record the approved state changes as dpkg selection states
```

**He intentado todo lo que se me ocurre pero nada funciona, incluso busqué ya en Google **

También se me presentan algunos errores como que el SO reconoce, a veces si y a veces no, el tradpad y, en algunos casos, no reconoce algunas letras. Ya intenté usar un teclado externo y da el mismo resultado. No se si tiene algo que ver.

Comment: prueba a cambiar los repositorios de ubuntu https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-apt-repository-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Esto es la sección para desarrolladores debes ir a https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: El error `Error de entrada/salida` indica fallas en el sistema de archivos. Sería conveniente que realizaras una prueba de disco duro, tanto lógica como física. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Esas *dependencias inclumplidas* corresponden a los controladores de video de Ubuntu. Si los modificas "a la fuerza" probablemente dejarás la interfaz gráfica inutilizable.

De todos modos, para intentar instalar cualquier paquete con dependencias incumplidas, se recomienda el uso de **aptitude**

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
    sudo apt-get install aptitude
    sudo aptitude install ElPaqueteConflictivo
```